# I'm looking for a list of C vulnerabilities like OWASP Top 10

Tags: c

I'm looking for a list of all vulnerabilities that can be present in C so I can practice them all.

I found this: [Category:C/C++](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:C/C++), but it's not of much use.

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. Finding an _exhaustive_ list (which seems to be what you're asking for) would be impossible as there may well be some no one is aware about. But here are some sources: [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3993712/476371) (in particular the CERT stuff [on C here](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/SEI+CERT+C+Coding+Standard)), [this PDF (presentation)](https://resources.sei.cmu.edu/asset_files/Presentation/2005_017_101_52657.pdf), and of course the book "Writing Secure Code".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These CWE lists will help you a lot:

[Weaknesses in software written in C](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/658.html)

[Weaknesses in software written in C++](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/659.html)

Answer (score 3):

Not a vulnerability list by itself, but 
[SEI CERT C Coding Standard](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/SEI+CERT+C+Coding+Standard) lists many “dangerous” code patterns which can be a source of vulnerabilities.

The book *The Art of Software Security Assessment* is a little old by now but still contains a lot of valuable advice.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great resource. You can find most of the material on SEI CERT website but the book is great.

[https://www.amazon.com/Secure-Coding-2nd-Software-Engineering/dp/0321822137](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321822137)